# Cannot find module '@modules' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: reactjs, module, vite, adminlte

I have the all the modules I am trying to import in the folder and import @modulename failed to detect them.

I did npm install but still having error

I really want to understand what is going on here, but I'm at a bit of a loss as to where to look next. Any suggestions?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mk0zM.png)
(Using React Vite)